# JSON dentro de un closure

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un *JSON*, por ejemplo:

```
var text = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}';
```

Y quiero insertarlo adentro de un closure en *JavaScript*, pero leer el *JSON* desde fuera del *closure*, no logro leerlo por fuera.

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {

return var text = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}';
}
    })();
```

Es un ejemplo, incluso después de parsearlo no logro sacar los datos del JSON, ni modificarlo. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no está en español.

Comment: Es que esto no sólo no tiene sentido, sino que además es un error: `return var text = ...`

Comment: Mueve `var text = { ... }` justo debajo de `var counter ...` luego donde pones `return var text = { .. }` remplazalo por `return text`. Esto ultimo es un error de syntaxis y lo anterior es porque para que se forme el clousure, la variable deberia estar fuera de la funcion retornada.

Answer (score 0):

Es que `return var` está mal... Hay que desacoplarlo de la siguiente manera, y además parsearlo, para que lo devuelva como objeto.

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {
        var text = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}';
        text = JSON.parse(text);
        return text;
    }
})();
```